# Apache 2.4 upgrade tips?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I'd like to upgrade my apache to 2.4 on a CentOS 5 VPS, for it's performance and reduced memory usage.

Any experience/tips to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have it running already ?

The 2.2 config should work almost verbatim; start from there.